# Is there a name for this kind of matrix?: arg max of each row is unique

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I would like to know if there is a name for an $n \times n$ matrix of real numbers where the index of the maximum value (arg max) of each row is unique, for example:

$M = \begin{bmatrix}
6 & 1 & -2 & 3 & 5\\ 
2 & -4 & 5 & 7 & 2\\ 
-5 & -1 & -3 & 5 & 7\\ 
-1 & 6 & -4 & 1 & 0\\ 
1 & 9 & -2 & 7 & -6
\end{bmatrix}$

In this case the max value of the row $[6,1,-2,3,5]$ is $6$, corresponding to index $0$,

So that the arg max corresponds to a vector:

$arg max(M) =\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
3 \\
4 \\
1 \\
2 \\
\end{bmatrix}^T$

I'm interested in this vector as a mapping.

I remember just enough linear algebra to know that this is functionally equivalent to the following orthogonal matrix:

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

And just enough to also be at least 80% sure that the matrix $M$ is itself not orthogonal (?). Does it have a name? Can anyone point me to a resource about this kind of matrix?

Disclosure: I'm a novice programmer (not a mathematician) trying to put an algorithm I wrote into mathematical language. This means that every statement above should be prefixed "correct me if I'm wrong, but...".

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Must entries be integers?

Comment: No they can be any float or int.

Updated to clarify!

Comment: A list of commonly used types of matrices which have well known names can be found in [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_matrices).  Briefly looking through and trying a few searches on the page, I did not personally find what you are describing, but that doesn't mean it isn't there or is known and just not included in the list.

Comment: I strongly doubt there is a special name, since nearly all matrices with real entries have this property.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Nearly all? In the case of $n \times n$ matrices with entries chosen independently from some fixed distribution, the (one-indexed) argmax of each row is uniformly distributed on $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ and the chance that each argmax is unique is $n!/n^n$.

Comment: With the edit and the defining feature being the locations of the max values, you could describe this as a constant multiple of a permutation matrix added to a matrix whose entries are all less than that constant.

Comment: @ConnorHarris the "nearly all" comment was made before it was clarified that he was talking about the *positions* of the maximums rather than the *value* of the maximums.  If we are talking about the values being distinct, then [almost every](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere) selection of $n^2$ real numbers according to some continuous distribution of real numbers will result in $n^2$ distinct real numbers.  Repeating a number occurs with probability zero.

Comment: "each row is uniformly distributed on {1,…,}" is not "real entries."